# Pass mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

I would like to know if there is a function or a simple way to pass the format date mm/dd/yyyy

For example: 11/01/2022 (November 1st 2022)

To this format yyyy-mm-dd

For example: 2022-11-01

Nowadays, I am slicing the date as a string, getting the day, month and year individually and put them together as I want, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you use the `date` datatype you'll never need to worry about the format - its only when you incorrectly use a string for a date that you get this issue.

Comment: You could however check the documentation for `CONVERT`.

Comment: Use a `date` datatype in the RDBMS. Date and time data types don't have a format, so worry about the way it is formatted in the *display* layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're storing a date in a TEXT field? That is bad, but if that's indeed the case, the first step is to first parse it into a DATETIME object:

```
PARSE('11/01/2022' AS datetime USING 'en-US')
```

Now that it's in a DATETIME, use FORMAT() to format it to your desired format:

```
SELECT  FORMAT( PARSE('11/01/2022' AS datetime USING 'en-US') , 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Returns:

```
2022-11-01
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-parse-into-datetime2) which has the `[USING culture]` option:

```
PARSE ( string_value AS data_type [ USING culture ] )
```

In your example

```
SELECT PARSE('11/01/2022' AS datetime2 USING 'en-US');
```

Output:

```
2022-11-01
```

---

The above gives you `date` type which should be good for most tasks but if you need to get a string in a preferred format you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

#### A. Culture specific output:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = PARSE('11/01/2022' AS datetime2 USING 'en-US');
SELECT FORMAT( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) 'US English'  
      ,FORMAT( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) 'British English'
      ,FORMAT( @d, 'd', 'en-au' ) 'Australian' 
      ,FORMAT( @d, 'd', 'de-de' ) 'German'  
      ,FORMAT( @d, 'd', 'zh-cn' ) 'Chinese Simplified (PRC)';
```

```
US English  British English     Australian  German      Chinese Simplified (PRC)
11/1/2022   01/11/2022          1/11/2022   01.11.2022  2022/11/1
```

(Please note some countries always use two digits for day and month and some don't)

#### B. Fixed format output:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = PARSE('11/01/2022' AS date USING 'en-US');
SELECT FORMAT( d, 'yyyy-MM-dd') 'yyyy-MM-dd';
```

```
2022-11-01
```